# Explanation behind arithmetic pointer post increment output in C

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, operator-precedence, post-increment

```
void x(){

     int x[] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}; 
     int *p = x + 1;

         while (*p++ >5)
         printf ("%d ", *p); 
         printf ("\n");

}
```

Output: {7, 6, 5}

I wanted to double check my rationale behind what the proper output for this is, given the precedence and associativity in C.

When the function is called, it executes top down, taking no arguments.

First we have an array x of 9 elements.

Second we have a pointer p, which points to element x[1];

Third, we jump into the while loop, which is true for everytime *p++ > 5. 
What is evaluated first here is post incrementing the address of p++, so for the first element x[1], we have a value of 8 which is greater than 5, so p is incremented (p++ = x[2] = 7) x[2] = 7 becomes the new *p value (since it points to x[2] now) and 7 is printed.

Next we have 7 which is greater than 5, p is incremented (p++ = x[3] = 6) so 6 is printed and then we have 6 which is still greater than 5, p is incremented (p++ = x[4] = 5) so 5 is printed, we have so far {7, 6, 5} printed.

Then we evaluate the position of x[4] which is 5, which is not greater than 5, so we jump out of the while loop and ends up with the output. {7, 6, 5}.

Is my reasoning for this question correct?

Comment: `*p++` is `*(p++)`.

Comment: `p` is incremented so that it points at `x[2]` which contains the value `7`; that is not quite the same as `p++ = 7`.

Comment: Your understanding is absolutely right. First pointer starts checking from x[1] (because of *p = x + 1)  i.e  8 and then prints next value because of  *(p++) so the final output will be {7, 6, 5}

Comment: No, p++ does not ever equal 7. p != 7 at any point in the program execution.

Comment: @jwdonahue I mean point to the value 7 which is x[2], since we're doing pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: @ToniHe, then write that. `p` is a pointer to int, it's value is not what it points to, therefore `p != 7`. If you are going to reason about C, do it in the C language. English is ambiguous in this case, whether you are referring to the value of `p` or the object it references, but C is quite explicit on this point. In other words, `*p == 7`.

Comment: The value of `p` in `while (*p++ >5)` is `p`. The post-increment is applied as a **side-effect** after the statement is evaluated and **before** `printf ("%d ", *p);`, so the printed value will be `x[2]`.

Comment: The standards reference is [C11 - 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4p2) *"The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)."*

Answer (score 4):

> Is my reasoning for this question correct?

Since the lines

```
 while (*p++ >5)
     printf ("%d ", *p);
```

in a more simple form is equivalent to

```
 while (*p >5)
 {
     p = p + 1;           // Or: p++; Or: ++p;
     printf ("%d ", *p);

 }
```

then **yes, your reasoning is correct**

If you are at beginner level I'll recommend that you avoid using pre-increment (`++x`) and post-increment (`x++`) in complex expressions. They are the cause of so many beginner mistakes. Only use them as single expressions. Keeping things simple, avoids many bugs.

Answer (score 3):

You can imagine the while statement

```
while (*p++ >5)
```

the following way

```
while ( 1 )
{
    int *tmp = p;
    ++p;
    int value = *tmp;

    if ( !( value > 5 ) ) break; 
    //...
}
```

As you can see neither element of the array is changed.

Initially `p` points to `x[1]`. So the value of `x[1]` is compared with `5` while the pointer `p` itself moves one position right and inside the body of the loop it points to `x[2]` and the value of `x[2]` is outputted.  And so on.

Take into account that the postincrement operator has higher priotity than the dereferencing operator and the value of the postincrement operator is the value of its operand before incrementing.

Consider also this simple demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2 };
    int *p = a;

    printf( "%d\n", *p++ );
    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1
2
```

Comment: And just to clarify, the comparison of value x[1] is done first before the pointer moving to the next value, because what got me confused was when I checked the precedence charts ++ has precedence over >, so I wasn't 100% if it was increment first then compare, or compare as is then move.

Comment: @ToniHe At first the postincrement operator is evaluated but its value is the value of its operand before incrementing. And the dereferncing operator is applied to this value.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix increment/decrement have high precedence, but the actual increment or decrement of the operand is delayed (to be accomplished sometime before the statement completes execution). So in the statement y = x * z++; the current value of z is used to evaluate the expression (i.e., z++ evaluates to z) and z only incremented after all else is done

Answer (score 0):

> Is my reasoning for this question correct?

Yes, aside from step 3.

```
while (*p++ >5)
```

`*p++ > 5` retrieves the value of `p`: the first time a pointer to `x[1]` or 8.  That original value of `p` is used to de-referenced and fetch the `int` 8.  `8` is compared to `5`.

Sometime during the above, `p` is incremented - before the next *sequence point*.  C does not specify when the that happens other than the value used to de-reference was the original value of pointer `p`.

Answer (score -3):

*p++ -> post increment/pre increment operator is having high precedence level than dereference operator. First pointer p is incremented. If it is pre increment operator than p is incremented to next address and then pointer is dereferenced. But in case of post increment the pointer increment will be postponed until the pending operation on the pointer p is completed i.e. dereferencing operation.

Your understanding is correct.